# Is there a Status="any"?

Tags: channel-entries

Within the eateries tag, is there a peramiter that equals status="any" that will pull all entries no matter the status (including 'closed')?

I thought status="not none"  worked, but it's not...

Comment: You can use the pipe glyph to indicate multiple statuses... `status="open|closed|etc"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `status="not fakestatus"` will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include "closed" entries, you'll need to specifically include that status in your channel_entries call — from the [Docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/channel/channel_entries.html#status): "Note that closed status entries will not be included in the results when using “not” regardless of whether it is in the piped list."

Maybe try `status="closed|not closed"` as odd as that may seem. If that doesn't work, you may have to include all of the statuses that you want in the piped list.

Answer (score 0):

status="closed|open"

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#status

Hope that helps

Comment: That only covers those 2 statuses, not "any" status.